# Specify meteor release for project?

Tags: meteor

Is there a settings or config file I can create that will permanently set a project to a specific version of meteor? It can be challenging to remember for each project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that information is in the **release** file located at /yourproject/.meteor/release

Comment: Yes, that's awesome! Works great.